# resized partition of Ubuntu Virtual Box successfully but can't resized it to actual size

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

I have Virtual Box installed on windows box and Ubuntu Vm created inside it. I want to extend this Ubuntu VM's partition. I did following successfully.

```
C:\ VBoxmanage modifyhd ubuntu14-server-64bit-study-docker_Clone-disk1.vdi --resize 30000
```

Now Partition size is 30Gb but actual size is 8G.

I tried with Gparted Iso/VM http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/#prettyPhoto but that is not working for me. So is there another way to do it ?

I want to resize it to 30GB. Is this possible **without data loss** ?

[image]

ps : I tried resizetofs but it didn't worked !

Comment: What do you mean by "actual size is 8G"? Is that the size of the file on your (real) hard drive? If so, is the VDI dynamically allocated? If it's dynamically allocated, then this is perfectly normal and the file will grow once you put more data on it (up to 30 GB).

Comment: my root partition which I want to extend is 8GB

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your virtual drive's partition layout.

Comment: Snapshot uploaded above

Comment: I meant the **partition** layout inside your virtual drive; i.e. add the output of `fdisk -l` (run it inside the VM).

Comment: # fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 31.5 GB, 31457280000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3824 cylinders, total 61440000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00056891

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    15204351     7601152   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        15206398    16775167      784385    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        15206400    16775167      784384   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       7.1G  6.3G  369M  95% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            361M  4.0K  361M   1% /dev
tmpfs            75M  496K   74M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            371M     0  371M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
root@ubuntu-study-docker:~/chef-repo#

Comment: /dev/sda is 31.5 GB  but my /dev/sda1  ie root is 7.1G  so I want to make it around 30Gb but without data loss

Comment: OK Got Gparted working Had located less memory for gparted VM so x was not starting......Now I want to confirm will there be data  loss If I extend /dev/sda1

Comment: There _shouldn't_ be, but operations on partitions are inherently dangerous, so I'd take a snapshot of the VM before trying to extend it.

Comment: I have backed it up but being root partition can't restore it to this new extended one

Comment: Yes, I know, but if something goes awry, having your data on a 7GB partition is better than having no data on a 30GB partition (or having a completely corrupted partition). Again, the resize _should_ work fine; I was just making sure you had a backup in case it didn't.

Comment: bty is resize possible without deleting partition as i want to merge an primary partition with unallocated extended partition without data loss of primary partition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44031/discussion-between-insert-name-here-and-ashish-karpe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted extended partition and swap then I was able to extend my primary ie sda1